# date_select and build issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I've got an Enrolment model as per below and am trying to use a date_select and an options_from_collection_for_select in the form view. I am having trouble creating as I don't know whether to use .build or .new and the date_select seems to be sending the day/month/year separately in the form, eg

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HUQmbkmoATm6P/Avl11wmYqMrYeXVTZ/qmYfC2dpAFM=", "enrolment"=>{"course"=>"First Aid", "expiry(1i)"=>"2012", "expiry(2i)"=>"2", "expiry(3i)"=>"20"}, "commit"=>"Create Enrolment", "group_id"=>"2"}
```

My Enrolment model...

```
class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible :course_id, :group_id, :expiry
  validates_presence_of :expiry, :course_id, :group_id 
end
```

In my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([:admin,@group,@enrolment]) do |f| %>
---
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :course %><br />
    <%= f.select :course, options_from_collection_for_select(@courses, 'name', 'name') %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :expiry %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :expiry, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year + 5 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my Enrolments controller

```
  def new
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    #@enrolment = @group.enrolments.build
    @enrolment = Enrolment.new
    @courses = Course.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @enrolment }
    end
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @course = Course.find_by_name(params[:enrolment][:course])
    @courses = Course.all
    #@enrolment = Enrolment.new(params[:enrolment])
    @enrolment = @group.enrolments.build(:course_id => @course.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enrolment.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_group_path(@group), notice: 'Enrolment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @enrolment, status: :created, location: @enrolment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @enrolment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I try to submit its giving me validation errors that my expiry can't be blank, how can I add this into the create method so it works? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just:

```
@enrolment = @group.enrolments.build(params[:enrolment])
```

Basically you're not using the information submitted by the user via form and this is the reason your expiry is nil. **Of course**, **you have to change your form a bit, to something like**:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@courses, 'id', 'name')
```

So you you're passing id instead of name.

Comment: thanks for that that works when i change the select fields name to course_id, <%= f.select :course_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@courses, 'id', 'name') %>